# Error while installing tensorflowjs (python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have built an ML model in Python, and I want to use it in a web app. Given the situation, I am trying to use tensorflowjs to convert the model into JSON. I used `pip install tensorflowjs` to install the package, but I am getting errors related to `tensorflow_decision_forest` :

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_decision_forests (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow_decision_forests`

`Failure to load the inference.so custom c++ tensorflow ops. This error is likely caused the version of TensorFlow and TensorFlow Decision Forests are not compatible.`

My configurations-

made a virtual environment using conda with Python version 3.8 (tried with 3.10, yet the problem persists).

`tensorboard == 2.13.0`

`tensorboard-data-server == 0.7.2`

`tensorflow == 2.13.0`

`tensorflow-estimator == 2.13.0`

`tensorflow-intel == 2.13.0`

`tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem == 0.31.0`

Tried installing tensorflowjs version - latest (4.17), 4.15, 4.2.0 and few very old versions

I have tried searching for the solution but there's not an exact solution just got to know that `tensorflow`*`decision`*`forest` is only available for linux. I have also tried various combinations of TensorFlow libraries that I have found online, yet nothing has worked. ([referred this](https://community.deeplearning.ai/t/failure-to-load-the-inference-so-custom-c-tensorflow-ops-this-error-is-likely-caused-the-version-of-tensorflow-and-tensorflow-decision-forests-are-not-compatible/533833))